# WSConfig adding BouncyCastleProvider fails

Tags: jboss, bouncycastle, wss4j

I'm seeing the following log statement if i turn the loglevel to debug:

```
|DEBUG|service thread 1-15|ws.security.WSSConfig||The provider FirstProvider was added at position: 3

|DEBUG|service thread 1-15|security.util.Loader||org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider from [Module "org.jboss.as.webservices.server.integration:main" ...
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:252)
    at org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:245)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.addJceProvider(WSSConfig.java:868)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig$5.run(WSSConfig.java:446)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig$5.run(WSSConfig.java:443)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.init(WSSConfig.java:443)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.config.CXFStackConfig.<init>(CXFStackConfigFactory.java:61)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.config.CXFStackConfigFactory.getStackConfig(CXFStackConfigFactory.java:45)
    at org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig.create(AbstractServerConfig.java:272)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.config.ServerConfigImpl.create(ServerConfigImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.service.ServerConfigService.start(ServerConfigService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

|DEBUG|service thread 1-15|ws.security.WSSConfig||The provider SecondProvider was added at position: 8
```

This happens because of the WSS4J library. I am wondering if i need to take any action. If i understand it correctly 2 providers have been added but adding the bouncycastle fails. I know that i could add the bc libs to jboss or jre but is this really necessary? The fact that it is "only" a debug statement makes me also wonder if it is necessary. Maybe somebody knows what this actually means and can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSS4J attempts to install the BouncyCastle provider if it is available, and logs that DEBUG level error if it is not (this behaviour will change in the next major release). There is nothing to worry about if you don't require BouncyCastle to be installed.